# Upload photos in background for more than 10 minutes in iOS

Tags: ios, onedrive, background-music

I have an iPhone application which needs to upload photos when the application is in background. Currently I am using the **beginBackgroundTask** method in **applicationDidEnterBackground**. Using this approach, my application continues to upload photos for 10 minutes in background and then gets suspended. But my requirement is to continue uploading in background even after the value of **backgroundTimeRemaining** becomes zero.

The Microsoft **SkyDrive** app just does the same thing and it turns out that they are using '***music***' as '***background mode***' in **info.plist**. But I didn't find any music file in the application bundle. Any idea how they are accomplishing this task ?

I have already tried to play silent music when application goes to background. But with this, the iOS shows media volume instead of ringer volume when I use the volume control key.

Any suggestions how my app can upload photos in background for more than 10 minutes ?

Answer (score 2):

Create an [`NSURLSessionUploadTask`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsurlsessionuploadtask?language=objc) to upload your content in the background.